# Angle reflect in Cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, angle

I am making a game in Cocos2d. I have a ball that will be shot at a flat surface (the top of the screen) how can I make it so the ball will travel, hit the surface, then reflect the angle and travel that direction? Does that make sense? Please tell me if it doesn't, and I will clarify. Thanks!

EDIT:

Here's an illustration of what I want

[Here](http://www.mediafire.com/?msleih6iscua1ik)

Comment: is the surface flat? or is it like many surfaces with different angles?

Comment: an image would be great, does the ball shoot with different angles?

Comment: Just to let you know I'm still thinking about it I will let you know once I figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build the game using box2d (in cocos2d). Then you will have that "effect" for free.

Comment: Not really "for free" because you need to [painstakingly] set up all the physics parameters (world, fixtures, bodies, density/friction/restitution etc), but this is a good advice nevertheless +1

Answer (score 0):

Once you launch a ball at an angle, say 50 degrees, add (cos(50)*speed) to his X position, and (sin(50)*speed) to his Y position.
When you detect the ball's y position has reached the surface's y position, just change the angle to -50.

But you must know that it only works if you want a reflection angle on a top surface, where it hits the top surface and bounces down.